# Australian bank lookup via BSB, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, bank

Is there a means of looking up a bank name & branch through Javascript?

Perhaps an external service or an complete data-set that can be hosted internally and accessed through JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [obtain BSBs from Australian Payment Network](https://bsb.auspaynet.com.au/public/BSB_DB.NSF/publicBSB.xsp) and load them into your database.

This is pretty good, but sometimes the list can be a little out of date.  Also, the banks may close a branch and remove it from this master list of BSBs.  However, transactions to that BSB will continue to work because they do a redirect to the new BSB.

Comment: This link is out of date.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone still looking, the APCA themselves publish a continually updated list of BSB numbers which you can download in CSV format [here](https://bsb.auspaynet.com.au/public/BSB_DB.NSF/publicBSB.xsp).

Comment: This link is out of date.